# Generate downloadable PDF's from HTML Tables on Rails

Tags: html, pdf, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm looking for a tool to create PDF's from HTML Tables, one compatible with Rails and Twitter Bootstrap.

I'm aware of Prawn but I'd like to know other tools. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: use an API like the one at http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/html-to-pdf-api - at least you'll be sure that it will support responsive design like the one from Twitter Bootstrap. Just try to throw a responsive site into the many tools and online converters available and see which ones truly work... It aint many.

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of these too:

- [RTeX](http://rtex.rubyforge.org/)
- [HTMLDOC](http://htmldoc.rubyforge.org/)
- [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit)

Answer (score 0):

[Pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) has recently been quite popular. It is quite easy to get started with.